# Simple association issue with rails and not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Here is my Schema file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150917104809) do
    create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
         t.datetime "created_at", null: false
         t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
         t.string   "name"
    end
    create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
        t.datetime "order_date"
        t.integer  "customers_id"
    end
end
```

Here are the models

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

The migration file for association is

```
class AddForeignKeyToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :orders, :customers
  end
end
```

Following the simple rails assoc example in the [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

I created a customer record using the command

```
Customer.create(name: 'Someone')
```

and now trying to create the order

```
@order = @customer.orders.create(order_date: Time.now)
```

Am getting an error with a NilClass

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `orders' for nil:NilClass
```

May be another pair of eyes of help to tell what am I doing wrong.

Comment: can you show the controller code?

Comment: Don't have a controller. Running this of rails console. Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your schema:

t.integer  "customers_id" should be t.integer  "customer_id"

Comment: also, you need to define the customer first: `customer ? Customer.create(name: 'someone')`

Comment: Sorry I meant to say, I added the migration code. The integer was done by rails. I did not edit the schema file. May be am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of `create` to `@customer`:

```
@customer = Customer.create(name: 'Someone')
@order = @customer.orders.create(order_date: Time.now)
```

It also looks like you have a typo in your schema. It should be:

```
t.integer  "customer_id"
```

EDIT: Your migration file is incorrect. It should be:

```
class AddForeignKeyToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :orders, :customer
  end
end
```

See the [`add_reference` API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference).

Comment: I followed the order of creation and the t.integer was done by rails. I have added the migration file to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add to `@ghr`'s answer, your error is thus: `for nil:NilClass`

This means that you're trying to call a method on an object which doesn't exist. Ruby actually assigns nil classes to an `NilClass` object, so it's errors aren't easily recognized unless you've spent time with them.

--

You have to assign `Customer.create...` to a `variable`, otherwise Rails doesn't have the data stored for you to work with:

```
@customer = Customer.create(name: "Someone")
@customer.orders.create
```

As a note, you don't need `order_date` in your `Order` model - `created_at` will handle that. If you removed the `order_date` column from your table, you'd be able to call the following:

```
#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :customer
   alias_attribute :date, :created_at
end

@customer.orders.first.date
```